# Dapper - call Oracle schema.package.function

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, dapper

I can call Oracle stored procedure and function with Dapper, but I have problems with calling a function inside of package.

**My error is:**

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 39:
PLS-00302: component 'funct' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

My code is :

```
using (IDbConnection cn = Connection)
            {
                var a = cn.ExecuteReader(oracleFunctionName, fnParameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            }
```

My parameters are ok, but it seems that Dapper can't resolve ORacle function naming `schema.package.function`  Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, it was a stupid mistake.

If you are receiving an ORA-06550 error when you try to invoke the stored procedure, then there are two possibilities:

you are invoking the procedure from a schema other than schema which does not have the appropriate permissions granted to allow it to invoke another user's procedure.

the procedure has not been created in the "your" schema.