# Executing an Oracle package's function using Dapper

Tags: oracle, dapper

I'm trying to execute am Oracle package's function using Dapper, but am getting an ORA-06550 error message:

`ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PLS-00221: 'MYFUNC' is not a procedure or is undefinedORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

I'm able to execute the function successfully in Oracle's SQL Developer:

```
DECLARE
  PARAM1 NUMBER;
  PARAM2 NUMBER;
  v_Return VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  PARAM1 := 1;
  PARAM2 := 2;

  v_Return := MYPACKAGE.MYFUNC(
    PARAM1 => PARAM1,
    PARAM2 => PARAM2
  );
  /* Legacy output:  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Return = ' || v_Return);
*/

  :v_Return := v_Return;
--rollback; 
END;
```

But when attempting to use dapper to do the same thing:

```
var storedProc = @"MYPACKAGE.MYFUNC";
return _connection.Query<string>(storedProc, new { PARAM1 = 1, PARAM2 = 2 }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
```

I get the error message above.  Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27620159/908929

Comment: Thanks @Maxwell77, but neither of those two conditions mentioned in the solution are the case.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error message and it disappeared after installing the Nuget package **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess** by Oracle.

It's not entirely clear to me what your function does. Is it recursive?
Anyway, when you use out parameters you should read this article:
[call-oracle-store-procedure-with-dapper](https://medium.com/@CodeCoo/call-oracle-store-procedure-with-dapper-c-b4176f636e11).
which is based on the class [OracleDynamicParameters](https://gist.github.com/vijaysg/3096151).

I also found this interesting, but I haven't tried it: the Nuget package [Dapper.Oracle](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Oracle/).